# Pandas read_csv reading floating values which are not present in the file

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am reading a CSV file using pandas and getting improper values in the result. I see floating-point values that are not there in the file itself: 
[image]

Whereas the csv file looks like this : 
[image]

I am not sure from where those floating values are coming from seems some kind of ordering
 How can I get rid of this 
This is the CSV file - 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qj-zfWoaYbMMbEin1K0dFbFHfDFr_t85/view?usp=sharing 
Also I created this case file using python code like

```
from csv import writer
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/digit-recognition/custom-data.csv', 'a') as f_object:
  
    # Pass this file object to csv.writer()
    # and get a writer object
    writer_object = writer(f_object)
  
    # Pass the list as an argument into
    # the writerow()
    writer_object.writerow(preprocessed_digits[0][0])
  
    #Close the file object
    f_object.close()
```

Comment: can you provide us 2 first lines of your file, read it with notepad or vim ...

Comment: Added the link to the actual CSV file being used

Comment: Thanks for adding the file, i test it and it works for me with `header=None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's doing that is because pandas can't have duplicate columns, so try:

```
data2 = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/digit-recognition/custom-data.csv', header=None)
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. I have pasted the exact CSV file that I am using

Comment: It gave the exact same output as before

Comment: @sunny How about now?

Comment: It's still the same. I am doing data2.head() after your code. If you see the output it has a pattern `0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4` I am wondering if it's outputting something else...

Comment: @sunny Edited my answer should wrok now, understood the problem now

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.read_csv('/mnt/ca_k060_pro_data/custom-data.csv', header=None)
```

explanation: your file doesn't contain columns, so pandas try to put finded values in columns, and he find a lot of duplications ...

Comment: Thanks that works. It's weird what was it outputting before? And why if it was just printing headers why it wasn't printing anything else. Also separately from the data frame returned could we fetch the first column and rest of the column separately

Answer (score 1):

You're csv file contains only one line. By default, `pd.read_csv` assumes the first line to contain the names of the table's columns. Therefore, 0.1, 0.2 and so forth, are not floating numbers, but a naming convention because the columns cannot have the same names.

Using the following code will not use the first line as column names and automatically assign numbers as column names, where path is the `path` to your csv file:

```
data2 = pd.read_csv(path, header=None)
```